# POST http://localhost:3000/claimdetails 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: typescript, http-post, angular2-services, web-frontend

I'm trying to post an object into json server but I got the 500 internal server error. Below are my codes.

**app.service**:

```
  createService(url: string, param: any): Promise<any> {
let body = JSON.stringify(param);
return this.http
  .post(url, body, this.options)
  .toPromise()
  .then(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleError);}
```

**Component**:

```
  save() {
var json = JSON.stringify({
  purpose: this.purpose
});

this.appService
  .createService('http://localhost:3000/claimdetails', json)
  .then(result => console.log("5. createService: " + result))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));}
```

**ERROR**:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMvgX.png)

Comment: Did my answer help you? Some feedback would be great

Comment: Hey Dinistro, your answer did make a lot of sense. Thanks for your help=)

Answer (score 0):

You used `JSON.stringify()` two times. Your json variable is already `JSON` when you pass it into `createService()`.

I would only keep it inside the `createService()`.

NOTE:
Do not use `.toPromise()` on `observables`. You can do the same with `observables`, no need for `promises`:

```
createService(url: string, param: any): Observable<any> {
    let body = JSON.stringify(param);
    return this.http
        .post(url, body, this.options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And then subscribe in your component